# If the air-jet garden hose swings back and forth, does the inhaling garden hose swing back and forth?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics

If the air-jet garden hose swings back and forth, does the inhaling garden hose swing back and forth?  I guess it will too, but I haven't experimented.  I don't know what the real situation is.  who knows?

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange wasn't around yet when Feynman was alive, but if it had been, then maybe he would have posted his now-famous [reverse sprinkler question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_sprinkler). Other related questions: [What happens if a rocket is filled with a vacuum instead of high pressured air?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74240), and [Why does blowing on a candle put it out but sucking doesn't?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75945).

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly https://coreidea372302082.wordpress.com/2021/08/29/what-will-happen-at-this-time/